# Regex expression to ignore first and last character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So I am trying to make a regex match for strings of the form:
`"catalog.schema.'tablename'"` .

The output I am looking for is just `catalog.schema.'tablename'` leaving out the quotes at the end position.

Can anyone help me out

I tried to do it with the expression
`/(?!^|.$)+[^\s]/` which leaves out the end quotes but matches each character.

So I modified it to `/(?!^|.$)+[^\s]+/g` . This matches the whole sentence but doesn't ignore the end quote.

Comment: can you clarify please why `/"(.*)"/` does not do what you want? Some more examples would be helpful of what to match, and what not to match.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the data arround your string and quotationmarks may be within the string.

Why not just this: `"(.*?)"`

https://regex101.com/r/oaS8o0/1

To answer the question in the title you might simply use:
`^.(.*)?.$`

https://regex101.com/r/FxJgtW/1

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
(?<=.).+(?=.)
```

Or, if you cannot use lookbehind:

```
(?!^).+(?!$)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/KMVG8S/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/KMVG8S/3).

Since `.` matches any char other than line break chars, the patterns just match any strings without their start and end chars.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match the first and the last character, you can just use a capture group instead of lookarounds and use the group 1 value.

The first `.` matches the first of (any) characters, the `(.+)` is a capture group that matches 1 or more characters, and the `.` at the end matches the last character of the string.

```
.(.+).
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQWJWw/1)

Or to get the text between the double quotes at the start and the end of the string using a negated character class and a capture group:

```
^"([^"]+)"$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OupXTZ/1)